# FosUserBundle and custom user registration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to figure out the registration process of the FosUserBundle and have been unable to do so.

I want to be able to register a user manually using custom fields and have been unable to see that in the code.

I have the registerAction in FosUserBundle and following it anywhere does not show me where the information is actually stored in the database:

```
public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'theme' => $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.theme'),
        ));
    }
```

How do I register a user manually?

Thanks

Comment: Did you even figure this out? i am having issues, particularly fromt he authenticateUser() function

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this in the FOSUserBundle docs?

[Using the UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md)

Apparently the service UserManager has the responsibility to actually save and update the user, you could create your own UserManager by following the guide.

Edit: Symfony has incorporated the documentation for the FOSUserBundle into their own documentation, as so the new link for the documentation is:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Comment: this is a broken link